# How to parse the dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

When I make a call, I am getting the response as a dict as below

```
{'NSE:TCS': {'instrument_token': 2953217, 'last_price': 2194.85}}
```

How do I parse and the last_price to a variable, say x

Comment: var = dict['NSE:TCS']['last_price']

Comment: thanks @ncica, it worked.

Comment: you're welcome, I'm glad that I helped